# ASP.NET - How to display image in browser without saving image in temp?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, type-conversion

I have a question- How to display image in browser without saving image in Temp folder? Is it even possible? My code have to reading images from database and displaying images in website. I actually try with converting data from database and I don't know what I want to do.
I try also with "imageHandlers", "FileStream", "Base64StringToBitmap" and nothing still works...
Please write example code or modify my code.

```
private void LoadImages()
{
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name, Data from tblFiles WHERE email = @CurrentUser";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@CurrentUser"].Value = User.Identity.Name;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                sdr.Read();

                string fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
                byte[] byte_image_string = ((byte[])sdr["Data"]);
                string image_string = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])sdr["Data"]) + fi.Name;

                imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
                imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
                imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
                imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);

                System.Drawing.Image newImage;

                if (byte_image_string != null)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byte_image_string))
                    {
                        newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

                        //I want here display image to browser without saving

                        //string newPhoto = "";
                        //newImage.Save(newPhoto);

                        imageButton.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + newPhoto;
                    }   
                }   
                conn.Close();
            }
        }    
    }
}
}
```

My example image code from database:

0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFE1018C45786966000049492A0008000000020031010200070000002600000069870400010000002E00000000000000476F6F676C6500000500009007000400000030323230099007000B0000007000000086920700080100007B00000002A00400010000006F02000003A0

Comment: you can try to delete the img file after displaing as ImageUrl.

Comment: It is only way to display image in website?

Comment: check my answer and tell me if you are ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in one of my projects:  Look src part

```
<p><a href='<%#"TheObject.aspx?O=" + Eval("ID") %>'><img runat="server" visible='<%#Eval("AttachmentID") != DBNull.Value %>' class="objPicture1" alt='<%Eval("Title") %>' width="340" height="260" src='<%#"~/Attachment.aspx?ID=" + Eval("AttachmentID")%>' /></a></p>
```

In Attachment.aspx you have this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Guid objID = //take the ID of the object ?ID=""

        DataRow attachmentRow = //fetch DataRow of the Attachment from Database

        if (attachmentRow == null)
            return;

        Response.ContentType = attachmentRow["ContentType"].ToString();// value of this is image/gif or image/jpeg and etc.
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])attachmentRow["Data"]); // Data is type image in my case                
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: My code: http://pastebin.com/Gn2CFzpw
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: I can't explain it better, make the query which takes the image in the Attachement.aspx and return it like byte[] response. In the image url write the correct link to attachment.aspx! You want to make you an example with exact your case ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating `Base64String` in wrong way. You are appending file name to it that should not work. just try following.

```
string image_string = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])sdr["Data"]);
```

Assign directly it to `ImageUrl`. no need to use `MemoryStream` here.

```
imageButton.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + image_string;
```